# Understanding the usage of つくin 体{からだ}につけたまま

Tags: grammar

> 体{からだ}につけたまま使うことができる.....

Please help me understand this form/usage of `つく`.

Since I don't know which kanji it corresponds to, it is difficult for me to make out what this phrase actually means.

Comment: The verb used in that sentence is つける, not つく.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case つく means you attach something to something and do not remove it (for a while). My dictionary says in this case it is written without kanji, however Google search reveals many usages of 付く in this role which means practically same - "put something somewhere".